# Django - filter for empty integer field not working

Tags: django, django-models

This is the queryset I'm using:

model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryText = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentCat = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

I am trying to query all the entries where parentCat is empty / not set.

```
queryset=Category.objects.all().filter(parent=null)
```

Obviously this is not working - what is the correct way of doing this query?

Comment: Is it just typo and you meant to write `.filter(parentCat = None)`, or are you trying to write JavaScript in Python?

Comment: Hi afshin, since the answer from bradley.ayers was correct it would be nice for you to mark his answer as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`null` is actually **not** a predefined object in Python. You want `None`:

```
queryset = Category.objects.filter(parentCat=None)
```

or

```
queryset = Category.objects.filter(parentCat__isnull=True)
```

These two are equivalent.